# axios does not return an array ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm taking axios to get a json server with an array

**attached json array**

*http://my-json-server.typicode.com/jee4nc/myjsonserver/lista*

The problem is that I want to assign that list of objects to another component through its properties

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import CardsGrid from "../Pages/CardsGrid"

class Axios_cards extends Component {

    constructor(props) {

        super(props)
        this.state = {
            courses : []
        }      
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('http://my-json-server.typicode.com/jee4nc/myjsonserver/lista')
        .then(response => this.setState({
                courses: response.data
            }))
    }
    render() {
        const {courses} = this.state
        return <CardsGrid courses={courses}/
    }
}

export default Axios_cards;
```

Exactly here

```
render() {
        const {courses} = this.state
        return <CardsGrid courses={courses}/>
    }
```

The component that receives the list of objects as props, is not receiving the array, since I did a validation to verify it
**I attach the component to which I assign the array through props**

```
const CardsGrid = ({courses}) => (
    <div className="ed-grid m-grid-3">
            {
                Array.isArray(courses) ?
            courses.map( e => 
                <Cards 
                id={e.id} 
                title={e.title} 
                description={e.description}
                image={e.image}
                price={e.price}
                key={e.id}  
                />) : null
            }
        </div>
)
```

Comment: What do you get if you add `console.log(courses)` in `CardsGrid`? (you will have to temporarily refactor it to use return for this).

Comment: You can also use the React Developer Tools (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en) to see the value of `courses` you are passing to `CardsGrid`.

Comment: Where could I find information on how to refactor a function component that receives props to a class component? I'm new to react :(

Answer (score 1):

The issue is here `axios.get('http://my-json-server.typicode.com/jee4nc/myjsonserver/lista')`. Most probably you are opening your app over secure (https) connection (i.e. https://my-app). But in the code you're trying to get insecure (http) resource. This is called mixed content and is blocked by browsers. You can read more about this [here](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/prevent-mixed-content/what-is-mixed-content)

So to resolve, just use https endpoint. Your backend seems to support https requests.

```
axios.get('https://my-json-server.typicode.com/jee4nc/myjsonserver/lista')
```

Working [sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/use-https-for-axios-8nqz7)

Comment: I just made the change, but still not receiving the list of objects using props. I've been learning javascript on my own, and I don't know how to see what CardsGrid is getting through props (courses)

Comment: To see what `CardsGrid` is getting thru props use either `console.log(courses)` and open dev console in a browser to see output (press F12 when in a browser and select Console tab) or change `<Card>` component to `<div>` or another standard HTML element like I did in my sample.

Comment: "Undefined" returns to me, it is strange considering that through axios it should be assigned correctly. In the axios_cards component I can't find the error that this undefined

Comment: Put `console.log` to `.then(response => { console.log(response); this.setState({ courses: response.data }))`.to see if it ever called. It may be some error which should be sown in the console of a browser.